# Either WSDL or wsimport and wsdl (mono) are horribly broken

Tags: java, wsdl, java-metro-framework, wsimport

**EDIT** I started off with the example given below, but I have now:

- Tried the example from the W3C spec. After fixing another error (binding was called `StockQuoteSoapBinding` in one place, `StockQuoteBinding` in another), it gives the same issue.
- Tried the mono generator `wsdl` to see if `wsimport` was to blame. It gives an equivalent error.

So it seems to me that despite all the hype about SOAP, it doesn't actually work - at least not as advertised. I can't believe nobody has run the most findable examples of wsdl through these generators.

**Original Question**

wsimport is failing on the following wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="OrdersService"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:os="http://example/schema/OrdersService"
  xmlns:tns="http://example/ns/OrdersService"
  targetNamespace="http://example/ns/OrdersService"
  >

  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema
      targetNamespace="http://example/schema/OrdersService">

      <xsd:element name="o:GetOrders">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="criteria" type="string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>

      <xsd:element name="os:GetOrdersResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="orders" type="string"/>
      </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>

    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="GetOrdersRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="os:GetOrders"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetOrdersResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="os:GetOrdersResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="GetOrdersPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetOrders">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetOrdersRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetOrdersResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="GetOrdersBinding" type="tns:GetOrdersPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetOrders">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="OrdersService">
    <wsdl:port name="GetOrdersPort" binding="tns:GetOrdersBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/svc/OrdersService/GetOrders"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

With:

```
parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] Schema descriptor {http://example/schema/OrdersService}GetOrders in message part "parameters" is not defined and could not be bound to Java. Perhaps the schema descriptor {http://example/schema/OrdersService}GetOrders is not defined in the schema imported/included in the WSDL. You can either add such imports/includes or run wsimport and provide the schema location using -b switch.
  line 35 of file:test.wsdl
```

Comment: "... it doesn't actually work ..."  --  I would have to agree.  Every time I have to touch SOAP, I know I'm in for a programming clusterbomb.  If this is the industry standard for interoperating over a wide area network, we're screwed.

Answer (score 6):

Although the question is rather old, here's a working WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="OrdersService"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:os="http://example/schema/OrdersService"
  xmlns:tns="http://example/ns/OrdersService"
  targetNamespace="http://example/ns/OrdersService">

  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example/schema/OrdersService">

      <xsd:element name="GetOrders">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="criteria" type="xsd:string" />
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>

      <xsd:element name="GetOrdersResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="orders" type="xsd:string" />
          </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>

    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="GetOrdersRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="os:GetOrders" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetOrdersResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="os:GetOrdersResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="GetOrdersPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetOrders">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetOrdersRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetOrdersResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="GetOrdersBinding" type="tns:GetOrdersPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document"
       transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetOrders">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="OrdersService">
    <wsdl:port name="GetOrdersPort" binding="tns:GetOrdersBinding">
      <soap:address
         location="http://localhost:8080/svc/OrdersService/GetOrders" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Things that I've changed:

- set `xmlns:xsd` to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` instead of `http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema` (the 1999 version is quite outdated)
- removed namespace identified from the schema elements (`GetOrders` instead of `o:GetOrders` and `GetOrdersResponse` instead of `os:GetOrdersResponse`) (namespace qualifiers are not allowed within the `name` attribute of an element or type definition)
- used the correct types for the subelements `criteria` and `orders`: `xsd:string` instead of `string`

---

I agree, that a WSDL might be difficult in the beginning, however, once you have a grip on it, there's nothing better than a clearly defined interface. If I had a choice, I would prefer a wsdl over a json-REST-API without hesitation. But I guess that's a matter of taste ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, wsimport requires external namespaces to be imported in order to use elements of them in the WSDL file. In your case:

```
 <import namespace="http://example/schema/OrdersService"/>
```

Comment: Even though the schema is internal to the document (ie defined in the type section)? Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: I now get 'missing required attribute "location" of element "wsdl:import"'. Of course the document doesn't really have a location since it's embedded.