# jax-ws :: wsimport and Apache CXF wsdl2java fail on a "normative" W3C WSDL specification example

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I am trying to get `wsimport` or Apache CXF `wsdl2java` generate stubs for "Example 1" of the [W3C WSDL 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_wsdl). (also copied verbatim at the end of the post).

The example appears to have a small typo, but even after replacing:

```
binding="tns:StockQuoteBinding
```

with

```
binding="tns:StockQuoteSoapBinding
```

both **wsimport** and **wsdl2java** still fail.

I've tried, the command line version (JAX-WS RI 2.2.4) and the Ant Task version (JAX-WS RI 2.2.8) of `wsimport` as well as the command line version of Apache CXF `wsdl2java` (2.7.6). They all seem to fail for the same reason more or less:

```
$ wsimport -version
JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
$ wsimport -d src-auto-wsimport/ -p foo.client  -Xnocompile specs/example1.wsdl 
parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] Schema descriptor {http://example.com/stockquote.xsd}TradePriceRequest in message part "body" is not defined and could not be bound to Java. Perhaps the schema descriptor {http://example.com/stockquote.xsd}TradePriceRequest is not defined in the schema imported/included in the WSDL. You can either add such imports/includes or run wsimport and provide the schema location using -b switch.
 line 31 of file:/home/brutus/jax-ws/wsdl/specs/example1.wsdl
```

From what I can see, the type it complains about (`TradePriceRequest`) is properly defined in the schema that's provided inside the WSDL file so I can't see why it fails to find it. (Apache CXF `wsdl2java` complains about the same type as well in a slightly different message)

Any ideas on what's wrong with this WSDL file?

### example 1 WSDL (verbatim from the W3C WSDL 1.1 spec linked above)

**NB:** you need to change `binding="tns:StockQuoteBinding` to `binding="tns:StockQuoteSoapBinding`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions name="StockQuote"

targetNamespace="http://example.com/stockquote.wsdl"
      xmlns:tns="http://example.com/stockquote.wsdl"
      xmlns:xsd1="http://example.com/stockquote.xsd"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
      xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<types>
   <schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/stockquote.xsd"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema">
       <element name="TradePriceRequest">
          <complexType>
              <all>
                  <element name="tickerSymbol" type="string"/>
              </all>
          </complexType>
       </element>
       <element name="TradePrice">
          <complexType>
              <all>
                  <element name="price" type="float"/>
              </all>
          </complexType>
       </element>
   </schema>
</types>

<message name="GetLastTradePriceInput">
    <part name="body" element="xsd1:TradePriceRequest"/>
</message>

<message name="GetLastTradePriceOutput">
    <part name="body" element="xsd1:TradePrice"/>
</message>

<portType name="StockQuotePortType">
    <operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
       <input message="tns:GetLastTradePriceInput"/>
       <output message="tns:GetLastTradePriceOutput"/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="StockQuoteSoapBinding" type="tns:StockQuotePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
       <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/GetLastTradePrice"/>
       <input>
           <soap:body use="literal"/>
       </input>
       <output>
           <soap:body use="literal"/>
       </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name="StockQuoteService">
    <documentation>My first service</documentation>
    <port name="StockQuotePort" binding="tns:StockQuoteBinding">
       <soap:address location="http://example.com/stockquote"/>
    </port>
</service>

</definitions>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Either WSDL or wsimport and wsdl (mono) are horribly broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682479/either-wsdl-or-wsimport-and-wsdl-mono-are-horribly-broken)