# JAX-WS: Compile Schema separate from WSDL

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws

If have a rather large schema that is used in several webservices, therefore I want to separate XSD compilation from WSDL compilation. In a simplified example, compiling in a single step works:

```
$ wsimport -verbose service.wsdl
parsing WSDL...

Generating code...

org/example/wsdl/mysvc/MySvcPortType.java
org/example/wsdl/mysvc/MySvcService.java
org/example/ns1/Element1.java
org/example/ns1/ObjectFactory.java
org/example/ns1/package-info.java
...
```

Compiling the xsd and using the resulting episode file does not work:

```
$ wsimport -b schema3.episode service.wsdl  
parsing WSDL...

[ERROR] Schema descriptor {http://www.example.org/ns1}element1 in
message part "part1" is not defined and could not be bound to Java.
Perhaps the schema descriptor {http://www.example.org/ns1}element1 is
not defined in the schema imported/included in the WSDL. You can
either add such imports/includes or run wsimport and provide the
schema location using -b switch.   line 9 of
file:...jaxepisode_element/service.wsdl
```

So how can I use the precompiled schema in wsimport?

Addendum:
Using the episode when including in another schema works and avoids new compilation (d3.jar contains the genrated classes from schema3 + schema3.episode as META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode):

```
$ xjc schema4.xsd d3.jar -extension
parsing a schema...

compiling a schema...

org/example/ns2/Element2.java
org/example/ns2/ObjectFactory.java
org/example/ns2/package-info.java
```

Without the precompiled package:

```
$ xjc schema4.xsd  -extension
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
org/example/ns1/Element1.java
org/example/ns1/ObjectFactory.java
org/example/ns1/package-info.java
org/example/ns2/Element2.java
org/example/ns2/ObjectFactory.java
org/example/ns2/package-info.java
```

WSDL:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://example.org/wsdl/MySvc" xmlns:ns="http://www.example.org/ns1" targetNamespace="http://example.org/wsdl/MySvc" name="MySvc">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.org/ns1" schemaLocation="schema3.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="myOpRequest">
    <part name="part1" element="ns:element1"/>
  </message>
  <message name="myOpReply">
    <part name="part1" element="ns:element1"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="MySvcPortType">
    <operation name="myOp">
      <input name="input1" message="tns:myOpRequest"/>
      <output name="output1" message="tns:myOpReply"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="MySvcBinding" type="tns:MySvcPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="myOp">
      <soap:operation/>
      <input name="input1">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output name="output1">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="MySvcService">
    <port name="MySvcPort" binding="tns:MySvcBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

schema3.xsd:

```
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/ns1" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/ns1" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <element name="element1" >
    <complexType >
        <sequence>
                <element name="name" type="string" />
        </sequence>
     </complexType>
   </element>
</schema>
```

schema4.xsd:

```
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/ns2" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/ns2" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/ns1" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://www.example.org/ns1" schemaLocation="schema3.xsd"/> 
    <element name="element2" >
      <complexType >
        <sequence>
          <element ref="ns1:element1" />
        </sequence>
       </complexType>
     </element>
</schema>
```

The generated episode file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/ns1">
    <schemaBindings map="false">
      <package name="org.example.ns1"/>
    </schemaBindings>
    <bindings scd="tns:element1">
      <class ref="org.example.ns1.Element1"/>
    </bindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1682479/1064325), and [this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/460978/Web-Services/java/WSDL-service)?

Comment: I haven't seen them before but after reading them I don't think that the solutions apllay to my case. Regarding the coderanch-trrwad: I already use elements for my messages, not types. Reagrading the othe SO question: I have the 2001 schema namespace, I have no namespace in my name-Attributes and `type="string"` is correct since xmls schema is the default namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use maven, separate for each and Generate with Apache CXF.

- http://cxf.apache.org/

I have an example that can help you.

properties:

```
 <properties>
    <apache.cxf.version>3.0.4</apache.cxf.version>
    <cxf-codegen-plugin.version>3.0.4</cxf-codegen-plugin.version>
    <cxf-xjc-plugin.version>3.0.3</cxf-xjc-plugin.version>
 </properties>
```

dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Run --> mvn clean install -Pgenerates-nfe-services

```
   <profile>
        <id>generates-nfe-services</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>generates-nfe-services</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <!--sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</sourceRoot-->
                                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                                <defaultOptions>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-npa</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-extension</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-keep</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </defaultOptions>
                                <wsdlOptions>
                                    <wsdlOption>
                                        <wsdl>
                                            ${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/br/gov/rs/sefaz/nfe/homologacao/NfeConsultaCadastro.wsdl
                                        </wsdl>
                                        <extraargs>
                                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                            <extraarg>br.gov.rs.sefaz.nfe.consulta.cadastro</extraarg>
                                        </extraargs>
                                    </wsdlOption>
                                </wsdlOptions>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Run --> mvn clean install -Pgenerates-layouts-nfe

```
    <profile>
        <id>generates-layouts-nfe</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>generates-layouts-nfe</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf-xjc-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!--sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</sourceRoot-->
                                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                                <xsdOptions>
                                    <xsdOption>
                                        <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/schemas/nfe/PL_008f/leiauteConsSitNFe_v3.10.xsd
                                        </xsd>
                                        <packagename>br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe.v310.leiaute.consulta.situacao.nfe
                                        </packagename>
                                        <extension>true</extension>
                                        <extensionArgs>
                                            <!--extensionArg>-npa</extensionArg-->
                                            <extensionArg>-extension</extensionArg>
                                        </extensionArgs>
                                    </xsdOption>
                                </xsdOptions>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

You can create a maven project to generate only the wsdl and another to only generate the xsd.

NOTE:

If his project does not require use the WSDL, switch to the json-rest-api.

**Use REST and be happy. \o/**

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think I will give CXF a try. Json is not really an option for.